# Why am I seeing "Go to Facebook.com" on my canvas page?

Tags: facebook, redirect

I keep seeing the facebook logo with a link that reads "Go to Facebook.com" in my canvas app while screens are loading.  Eventually the app loads fine, but what is this and how can I avoid it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there because you are doing a "frame level" redirect when you are jumping to Facebook for authentication (i.e. you are using something like `header('Location:xyz')` in PHP or `location.href=xyz` in javascript). You need to do a page-level redirect, which is why the doc sample code uses `top.location=xyz` javascript calls. Because you are not breaking out of the iframe, Facebook is putting up the intermediate link screen to do it for you.

Comment: I understand the reason for doing top.location during auth, but why can't we do php header redirects? And is EVERY link suppose to reload the entire browser window?  Appreciate the help.

Comment: You can't use header redirects because they can only affect the frame containing the page, and you need to affect the parent frame. And no, you don't need (or want) to reload the entire window on every link, it's only necessary when you do the authentication.

Comment: I use all three where appropriate.  Are you telling me that facebook is following up all my php header redirects with a top.location redirect?  How else should I direct my frame pages to myself to avoid this?

Comment: I think we might be a little out of sync here. You only need to do a top-level redirect when jumping to the Facebook authentication url. In that specific case, you must avoid the header redirect and use a javascript top.location redirect. For links/redirects within your own site (to one of your own pages which you want to appear within the iframe) you may use normal links, header redirects, javascript location.href, etc. The "Go to Facebook" page you are seeing happens *only* when you are a) jumping to a url at facebook.com and b) not using javascript top.location to do it.

Comment: OK we were out of sync and now we're not =) I am seeing "Go to Facebook" when I do php header redirects to myself.  I just setup a test script to confirm.

Comment: Sounds like there is a library or framework that is doing something "behind the scenes" concerning authentication. If you do a redirect to your own page that includes just straight html, it should work like you expect. Probably some includes on the destination page are doing a second redirect to facebook.com.

Answer (score -2):

`self.location.href` inside iframe instead of `header()`